# What does 'vivarious' mean?

Tags: meaning

There is such a word, but it seems to not have a definition. Several examples of using this word is as follows:

> There was the same lithe, wiry frame, unworn by much endurance, the sloping brow, expanding to a wedge-like shape at the temples, and the quick, keen, **vivarious gray eye**, as I remembered them in 1845.
>
> — Bayard Taylor, At Home and Abroad: A Sketch Book of Life, Scenery ... (1860)

and

> ... he had expected **a vivarious playmate** ...
>
> — newspaper article (1889)

and

> Calandra sought to break down the borderline between art and life by transforming the pedestal into a **vivarious battle scene** which extends into our space because of its landscape character.
>
> — Umberto Boccioni, ‎Philip Rylands (1996)

and

> At night her carmine finger-nails dig **her own vivarious history** clear of all misinterpretation and point the way of others' ruin before marking me for life.
>
> — [*Westerly*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=c8JDAQAAIAAJ&q=dig+her+own+vivarious+history+clear+of+all+misinterpretation&dq=dig+her+own+vivarious+history+clear+of+all+misinterpretation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAGoVChMIm82Jk52yxwIVZBbbCh1QEARQ) pub. University of Western Australia, 1966

and

[image: Image of print book]

> In **vivarious animals**, the birth awakens all the tenderness of a parent, which lasts as long as it is needed
>
> — Rebecca Edridge, [*The Scrinium*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0bgBAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334&source=bl&ots=BqTCAIVZ6y&sig=FD-IUvrAp-jx-rod_iADNFBD8hQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1822)

Comment: There is no entry in the OED for *vivarious*. A *vivarium* is a place where living animals are kept e.g. an *aquarium* is a form of *vivarium*.

Comment: Can you give an example of using this word? Moreover, maybe this could help : http://kmarchipelago.wikidot.com/forge-spells:vivarious-refrain

Comment: do you perhaps mean vivacious (attractively lively and animated) or vicarious (Experienced or felt by empathy)?

Comment: What's funny is that I was looking for some other word and mis-typed. While looking "vivarious" up I found quite a few references. But no definition. Hence, asking experts here.

Comment: Note to reviewers: the examples were supplied in comments (now deleted as included in the post).

Comment: @AndrewLeach They still need sources! I can't see deleted comments - if they comments contain source details would you be willing to add them to the post?

Comment: The OP needs to add sources if he knows, although it's highly likely that copyright has expired, and they are obviously quotes so there isn't any plagiarism. But they are material to the question (see my answer!)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be based (at least in part) on a false assumption (that 'vivarious' is a word rather than a rare misprint for 'vivacious'). Admittedly, it may be a nonce usage in the Edridge work.

Comment: If you search for the word in quotes in Google Books, you can find more uses that aren't typos. There is something called "vivarious flirtation" mentioned in Bulletin of University of Oklahoma in 1933. It is also mentioned in "Rendezvous: Idaho State University Journal of Arts and Letters" from 1991 that isn't a typo.

Comment: Interesting that a google search for vivarious brings up two identical links to this page .I don't think I've ever seen that happen...

Comment: I'm thinking there's a similar word that means "giving live birth".  Ah, here it is: [viviparous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/viviparous).  The last quote above would appear to fit that word.

Comment: "If you search for the word in quotes in Google Books, you can find more uses that aren't typos"  You made a typo.  You meant "If you search for the word in quotes in Google Books, you can find more uses that are also typos"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first quote comes from *At Home and Abroad: A Sketchbook of Life, Scenery and Men* by [Baynard Taylor](http://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/007704119) and is ***vivacious:***

[image: Image of book]

> There was the same lithe,
>   wiry frame, unworn by much endurance, the sloping brow,
>   expanding to a wedge-like shape at the temples, and the
>   quick, keen, vivacious gray eye, as I remembered them in
>   1845.
>
> via [Mocavo.com](http://www.mocavo.com/At-Home-and-Abroad-a-Sketch-Book-of-Life-Scenery-and-Men-2/237362/366?)

I can't find all the other quotes online but where they are not found it's entirely likely that they are a misreading of *vivacious* too. Optical character recognition may miss the very thin tail of *c*, only registering the left-hand thick stroke and terminal ball or serif and mistaking it for *r*.

The quotes which are obviously and verifiably correctly *vivarious* — that is, *Umberto Boccioni, Westerly* and *The Scrinium* — all appear to mean simply *living*.

The word does not appear in OED, which is testament to its rarity: even OED can't list **every** word used in print, although I would have expected the three examples here to be enough to trigger its inclusion.

The *viv-* comes from Latin *vīvĕre,* to live; and OED does list the *-arious* suffix:

> < Latin *-ārius, -a, -um* ‘connected with, pertaining to’ + **-ous** *suffix*   (as if < Latin *-āriōsus;* cf. *cariōsus,* carious). The reg. English repr. of *-ārius* is **-ary** *suffix*<sup>1</sup>; but the compound suffix is of occasional use, as in *cibarious, gregarious, temerarious, vicarious,* and as a by-form in *arbitrarious, contrarious,* etc. (*Hilarious,* < Latin *hilari-s + -ous,* seems to owe its form to association with this suffix.)

That being the case, I don't believe the writers intended *vivarious* to mean "pertaining to life" as one might say that a [warm-blooded] animal has a *vivarious warmth* — it's warm while it's alive. I believe they have mistakenly coined the word and it would have been better to have been *vivarous,* where the *-ous* suffix derives from Latin *-osus.* From the OED again:

> < classical Latin *-ōsus (-a, -um),* forming adjectives, with the sense of ‘abounding in, full of, characterized by, of the nature of’, e.g. *cōpiōsus* copious *adj., dolōrōsus* dolorous *adj., fāmōsus* famous *adj., generōsus* generous *adj.* and *n., glōriōsus* glorious *adj., spīnōsus* spinous *adj., viscōsus* viscous *adj.,* etc.

*Vivarious* is comfortingly similar to *vicarious,* which might explain why that form was chosen. Tim Lymington has posited that Edridge may have intended [*viviparous*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/viviparous) in *The Scrinium*.

It's entirely possible that OED also believes *vivarious* to be a mistake, which is why it's not included even though there are probably sufficient instances to warrant it.

Comment: The second and probably the fourth should clearly be *vicarious*: the *Scrinium* one should, I think, be *viviparous*. And you have my upvote, if only for pointing out that, despite what OP believes, finding half a dozen examples in the entire published corpus of English does not in fact mean that a word exists.

Comment: @Tim You're probably right about *Scrinium* being a misprint/malapropism for what should have been *viviparous*. I'm not sure that *vicarious* fits any of the usages, though.

Answer (score -1):

the vi- in vicarious comes from *[vicis](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vicarious&allowed_in_frame=0)* which if added to *[various](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/various)*

> *vicis* - a change, exchange, interchange; succession, alternation,
> substitution
>
> plus
>
> *various* - Having or showing different properties or qualities

we could get a meaning like, "**having or showing alternating/changing properties or qualities**". Which if used to refer to eyes (I don't understand the example using eve, I suspect a misspelling) would make me think of heterochromia (different colored eyes).

And I think it works quite well with "her own vivarious history clear of all misinterpretation"

Comment: I don't think that 'words' that (2) people have to analyse and explain before readers can understand them (1) aren't even in OED 'work well' at all.

Comment: agreed, although I did enjoy the exorcise.

Comment: You mean the exercism.  :)

Answer (score -2):

It's a typo.

Note that if you take **almost any word**, and **form a similar typo**, you will find **about the same number of examples** of that typo as you have found here.

I must say that, folks asking really *concerned! interested! intense!* questions about typos ... is a bit of a plague on this site.

IJAFT.  It's Just A Typo.